# JDBI's @BindBean doesn't find named parameters in bean class during INSERT

Tags: java, mysql, dropwizard, jdbi

I am consistently getting the following exception below when inserting values using JDBI's @BindBean into my Mysql database within Dropwizard. The problem seems to be that JDBI is unable to find the properties in the bean. I already isolated the issue into a separate project, but can't figure out where this is going wrong. I would be very grateful for some advice.

```
org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: Unable to execute, no named parameter matches "title" and no positional param for place 0 (which is 1 in the JDBC 'start at 1' scheme) has been set. [statement:"INSERT INTO `car_tbl`(`title`, `teaser`, `ext_description`, `create_date`, `teaser_image_url`, `teaser_image_color`) VALUES ( :title, :teaser, :extDescription, unix_timestamp(), :teaserImageUrl, :teaserImageColor)", located:"INSERT INTO `car_tbl`(`title`, `teaser`, `ext_description`, `create_date`, `teaser_image_url`, `teaser_image_color`) VALUES ( :title, :teaser, :extDescription, unix_timestamp(), :teaserImageUrl, :teaserImageColor)", rewritten:"/* CarDAO.createCar2 */ INSERT INTO `car_tbl`(`title`, `teaser`, `ext_description`, `create_date`, `teaser_image_url`, `teaser_image_color`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, unix_timestamp(), ?, ?)", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{class:class com.javaeeeee.dwstart.db.Car}, finder:[]}]

    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.ColonPrefixNamedParamStatementRewriter$MyRewrittenStatement.bind(ColonPrefixNamedParamStatementRewriter.java:158)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.SQLStatement.internalExecute(SQLStatement.java:1318)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.Update.executeAndReturnGeneratedKeys(Update.java:78)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.UpdateHandler$1.value(UpdateHandler.java:51)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.UpdateHandler.invoke(UpdateHandler.java:75)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject.invoke(SqlObject.java:175)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject$1.intercept(SqlObject.java:75)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.CloseInternalDoNotUseThisClass$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8f365cd7.createCar2(<generated>)
    at com.javaeeeee.dwstart.db.TestDatabase.testCreatecar2(TestDatabase.java:60)
```

This is my value object

```
public class Car {
    public Long carId;
    public String title;
    public String teaser;
    public String teaserImageUrl;
    public String teaserImageColor;
    public String extDescription;
    public Long createDate;
}
```

And I have created the following DAO to make use of the @BindBean functionality as described in http://jdbi.org/sql_object_api_argument_binding/ - both methods for inserting fail.

```
package com.javaeeeee.dwstart.db.dao;

import com.javaeeeee.dwstart.db.Car;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.BindBean;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.GetGeneratedKeys;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlUpdate;

public interface CarDAO {
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO `car_tbl`(`title`, `teaser`, `ext_description`, " +
            "`create_date`, `teaser_image_url`, `teaser_image_color`) " +
            "VALUES ( :c.title, :c.teaser, :c.extDescription, unix_timestamp(), " +
            ":c.teaserImageUrl, :c.teaserImageColor)")
    Long createCar(@BindBean("c") Car car);

    @GetGeneratedKeys
    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO `car_tbl`(`title`, `teaser`, `ext_description`, " +
            "`create_date`, `teaser_image_url`, `teaser_image_color`) " +
            "VALUES ( :title, :teaser, :extDescription, unix_timestamp(), " +
            ":teaserImageUrl, :teaserImageColor)")
    Long createCar2(@BindBean Car car);
}
```

And this is my table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cardb`.`car_tbl` (
  `car_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `teaser` VARCHAR(2048) NULL COMMENT '',
  `ext_description` VARCHAR(4096) NULL COMMENT '',
  `create_date` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
  `teaser_image_url` VARCHAR(2048) NULL COMMENT '',
  `teaser_image_color` VARCHAR(8) NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `idx_create_date` USING BTREE (`create_date` ASC)  COMMENT '')
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And I am using the following JUnit integration test to recreate the error:

```
public class TestDatabase {
    private DBI dbi;
    private Handle handle;
    private CarDAO carDAO;

    @Before
    public void setUpDatabase() throws Exception {
        Environment environment = new Environment( "test-env", Jackson.newObjectMapper(), null, new MetricRegistry(), null );
        dbi = new DBIFactory().build( environment, getDataSourceFactory(), "cardb" );
        carDAO = dbi.onDemand(CarDAO.class);
        handle = dbi.open();
    }

    protected DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory()
    {
        DataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DataSourceFactory();
        dataSourceFactory.setDriverClass( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
        dataSourceFactory.setUrl( "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/cardb" );
        dataSourceFactory.setUser( "root" );
        dataSourceFactory.setPassword( "root" );
        return dataSourceFactory;
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreatecar(){
        Car car = new Car("Test car","Test car teaser","http://localhost:8080/","#ff0000","car test description");
        Long carId = carDAO.createCar(car);
        assertNotNull(carId);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreatecar2(){
        Car car = new Car("Test car","Test car teaser","http://localhost:8080/","#ff0000","car test description");
        Long carId = carDAO.createCar2(car);
        assertNotNull(carId);
    }
}
```

I am using Java 1.8.0_05, Dropwizard 0.9.2 and MySQL 5.7.9.

Comment: BindBean claims to work with JavaBeans. JavaBeans require getter and setters. Could you try to add getters and setters to your Car class?

Comment: That actually fixed it. Which is weird, because I have a different class that actually works without any getter/setter combination. Thank you so much.

Comment: alright, I moved the question to a proper answer so you can mark this question as complete.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

BindBean claims to work with JavaBeans. JavaBeans require getter and setters.

Please add getters and setters to your Car class.

Comment: Note: if you have a field named `isFoo`, it wants the getter to be named `getIsFoo()` not `isFoo()`

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem of:

```
    UnableToCreateStatementException, message: Missing named parameter 'isFavorite'.
```

That was because my getter was just:

```
    public boolean isFavorite() {
            return this.isFavorite
    }
```

Then I changed it to `getIsFavorite()` and it worked.
Note that this getter must be `public`.